# Groups of real numbers

Tags: group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Groups of real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61230/groups-of-real-numbers)

A group as we all know is a set A with a binary  operation "*"  defined on it such that for every  a,b belongs to A a*b belongs to A, the operation is assocaitive, there exists an identity element and for every a in A there exists a unique p in A such that a*p=identity element.
Can anyone provide me examples of groups where the operation defined on the set is not  addition + or multiplication x.

Comment: -1: The question admits infinitely many answers (in a very strong sense!) and is answered in literally every course in group theory (e.g., any non commutative group does the trick).

Comment: Should this question get made into a community wiki, or have I misunderstood the term?

Comment: @PseudoNeo: That doesn't make it any less valuable a question, because this person might not have the opportunity to attend a course in group theory. I really don't think we should be picky about which questions we think too 'standard' to ask. It's highly conceivable that they might be learning group theory from a non-standard (or just plain bad) textbook and not know it.

Comment: If one interprets your question as "what topological/Lie group structures exist on subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$", it becomes very interesting!

Comment: @Billy- So, you think I.N.Herstein's algebra text  is a bad one?

Comment: @Billy: by "every course", I meant every material about group theory. Even if the OP hasn't access to teachers or books, there's still plenty of Internet material, starting with wikipedia.

Comment: @Primeczar: I don't know it.

Comment: @PseudoNeo: Right. But, again, how do we know that the OP isn't simply (completely inadvertently) using poor material? Wherever they're learning group theory from, if the only examples they've come across are examples of multiplication and addition, something's clearly gone wrong, and it's not their fault. It is no one's position here to judge others on the quality of the free online material (or book, or teacher) they happen to be learning group theory from. They possibly don't know any better, and that in itself is a great reason to ask.

Comment: Well, regardless of the more or less improbable circumstances of the OP's biography one can think of, I think that a group theory question answered in each of the first answers spat out by a "group theory" Google query isn't a great MSe question. My "-1" only says that: I haven't judged anyone, nor asked for the deletion of the question or the stoning of the OP... BTW, a group theory course mentioning only the addition and multiplication of numbers wouldn't be “non-standard”, “plain bad” or “poor”: it would be an atrocious piece of fæces.

Answer (score 22):

Here are some examples I've used (class examples, homework, tests, etc.):

Let $G = \{x \in \mathbb R: x \neq -1\}$ and define $*$ by $a*b=a+b+ab$.

Fix an integer $k$. Let $G = \mathbb Z$ and define $*$ by $a*b = a + b + k$.

Fix a real number $\beta > 0$. Let $G = \{x \in \mathbb R: x > 0 \}$ and define $*$ by $a*b = \beta ab$.

Let $G = \{x \in \mathbb R: -1 < x < 1 \}$ and define $*$ by $a*b = \frac{a+b}{1 + ab}$.

Let $G = \mathbb R$ and define $*$ by $a*b = \sqrt[3]{a^{3}+b^{3}}$.

More examples can be obtained by the following general methods:

Let $(G,\bullet)$ be a group and fix $g \in G$. Then $(G,*)$ is a group, where $*$ is the operation defined by $a*b = a \bullet g \bullet b$.

Let $(G,\bullet)$ be a group and $f:G \rightarrow G$ be a 1-1 and onto (i.e. bijective) function. Then $(G,*)$ is a group, where $*$ is the operation defined by $a*b = f^{-1}\left(f(a) \bullet f(b) \right)$.

If we go outside the realm of real numbers for the set $G$, then far more exotic examples are possible. For example, let $X$ be any set and let $P(X)$ be the set of subsets of $X$. Then $\left( P(X),\Delta \right)$ is a group, where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference operation defined by $A \Delta B = (A-B) \cup (B-A)$. For another example, let

$$G = \left\{ x, \frac{x + 5}{3 - x}, \frac{x - 5}{x-1}, \frac{3x-5}{x+1} \right\},$$

whose elements are functions from ${\mathbb R} - \{-1,1,3\}$ into ${\mathbb R} - \{-1,1,3\}.$ Then $(G,*)$ is a group, where $*$ is the operation of composition of functions.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I appreciate this contribution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a real number x not equal to 0 or 1. There is a group of order 6 generated by the operations which take $x\to \frac 1 x$ and $x \to 1-x$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to note that the way you want to think about groups is not necessarily as number systems (a role better suited for rings), but as symmetries or in terms of actions.

To make this more mathematically precise, for any set $X$, you can form a group by looking at all one-to-one, onto maps from $X$ onto $X$, let's call this $\operatorname{Perm}(X)$. The binary operation is composition, the identity is the the map $x\mapsto x$, and the inverse is the compositional inverse. Lots of examples of groups can be found by considering subgroups of $\operatorname{Perm}(X)$, namely those that preserve additional "structure".

So for concrete examples, if $X=\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$, then $\operatorname{Perm}(X)$ is the $n$-th symmetric group and is denoted $S_n$.

If $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, then we can look at the non-singular linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb{R}^n$. This group is called $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, and it's the subgroup of $\operatorname{Perm}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ that preserves the vector space structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Neither of these (for $n>1$) are subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$ with addition or multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the set has just one real number, it's not equal to 1 or 0, and closure holds for the binary operation *.  In other words, (a*a)=a.  Every such structure qualifies as a group, and they all come as isomorphic to each other.

Suppose the set has two distinct real numbers "a" and "b" and neither of them equals 1 or -1.  Suppose the binary operation has this table:

```
   a  b
a  a  b
b  b  a
```

Every structure of this class qualifies as a group, and they all come as isomorphic.