# Groups of real numbers

Tags: group-theory

In [my last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60759/groups-of-real-numbers) I asked for examples of groups  formed by real numbers where the operation is something different from addition or multiplication.
With these words I think I could not convey what I wanted.
 In an attempt for further clarity in conveying my query I state the question as follow

" Are there examples of groups formed by real numbers where the binary operation of the group does not involve any addition or multiplication"
 I hope this time  I will be getting appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you need the elements of the group to be all real numbers, or just a subset?

Comment: Also, what does "involves" mean?

Comment: @charles - Yes I want  groups with the mentioned property whose elements are all real numbers.

Comment: It's not an answer, but one can show that any $C^1$ group structure on $\mathbb R$ (that is, a group structure whose multiplication $*$ and inverse are continuously differentiable functions) is in fact the addition in disguise (precisely: there is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x*y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

Comment: @charles- I meant the binary operation should not be multiplication.

Comment: For example, a+b, or a.b or a+b+(a.b), in a nutshell there should not be any addition or multiplication .

Comment: God forbid you get *inappropriate* answers...

Comment: Given an operation, how can I determine if it involves addition or multiplication?

Comment: Just to insist on The Chaz's irony, I find your opening of three questions on MSe/MO and the comments “I hope this time I will be getting appropriate answers” (here) and ”I hope in this site I may get better answers as compared to its stack exchange counterpart” (in MO) insulting.

Comment: **HINT** $\ $ Take any group $\:G\:$ with the same cardinality as $\:\mathbb R\:$ and transport the group structure of $\:G\:$ to $\:\mathbb R\:$ along any bijection of their underlying sets.

Comment: You *do* know that $\mathbb{R}$ is by itself just a continuum, right?

Comment: Rather bad form to open a second question with **identical** title and which is nothing but an attempt at explaining what you meant with the original. Much better would have been to **edit** your old question to add your clarification. As it is, I have voted to close [the old question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60759/groups-of-real-numbers) as a duplicate, and invite you to not do this again in the future.

Comment: @PseudoNeo do you have a source for your statement about $C_1$ group operations on $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Well, I've learnt about it in a French exercise book on differential calculus (Rouvière, *Petit guide de calcul différentiel*). After your question I googled a bit and found this Conrad blurb: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/relativity.pdf which may suit you. (These blurbs are so amazing that one of these days I will launch a kickstarter project to make a bronze statue of K. Conrad).

Answer (score 13):

Let $W$ be the collection of all bijections from the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.  It is a standard fact that the cardinality of $W$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

It follows that there is a bijection $\phi: \mathbb{R}\to W$.  Instead of using the notation $\phi(a)$, we will use the perhaps clearer notation $\phi_a$

For any real numbers $a$, $b$, define $a\ast b$ as follows.
$$a\ast b=\phi^{-1}(\phi_a\circ \phi_b).$$

Note that $\phi_a$ and $\phi_b$ are bijections from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, and $\phi_a\circ\phi_b$ is the *composition* of the functions $\phi_a$ and $\phi_b$, defined by 
$$(\phi_a\circ\phi_b)(n)=\phi_a(\phi_b(n)),$$
(apply $\phi_b$, then apply $\phi_a$ to the result).  It is clear that $\phi_a\circ\phi_b$ is a bijection.

It is not hard to verify that under the operation $\ast$, the real numbers form a group, indeed a very non-abelian group.  Ordinary sum and product are nowhere involved in the definition of $\ast$.

**Comment**: The above answer is a special case of the general construction method "You can realize any group whose cardinality is the continuum this way" in the answer of Yuval Filmus.

Comment: That's simply applying **transport of structure** to a specific group of cardinality $\mathbb R$ - which has already been mentioned by Yuval. Of course one can do exactly the same for *any* group of cardinality $\mathbb R$, as Yuval mentioned.

Comment: Agreed! However, the OP seems to want to avoid *any* mention of conventional addition and multiplication. The example was designed to do precisely that. "Scrambling" a group of cardinality $c$ that is based on addition and/or multiplication might not qualify as an example to the OP.

Comment: While I agree that Yuval's first paragraph doesn't meet the goal of "not involving addition", I interpret his second paragraph as referring to general transport of structure. It would be helpful to mention that terminology, and to stress that this answer is a specific case of this general technique alluded to in Yuval's answer. Else the relationship may not be clear to students. Such matters are often confusing to students attempting to first grasp the concepts of algebraic structure and isomorphism.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Done. I think.

Comment: Thanks. Of course I think it is a good idea to present a specific example as you do. My only concern is that students may not realize that both answers are examples of the general technique of transporting algebraic structure along a bijection (set-theoretic isomorphism) - one that is rather trivial from an algebraic perspective. Alas, this takes some nontrivial algebraic experience to appreciate, so it is difficult to convey to beginning students.

Comment: @Bill, André: Is this really a special case of Yuval's construction? Unless I'm missing something, the latter always yields an abelian group, while this one does not.

Comment: @Rahul As I said, I read Yuval's second paragraph as saying that one can transport the group structure of any group of same cardinality to the set $\mathbb R$. That's precisely what Andre does - for one specific group.

Answer (score 5):

Choose a permutation $\pi$ of the real numbers, and define a group using $f(a,b) = \pi^{-1}(\pi(a) + \pi(b))$. While this "involves" addition, if you don't know $\pi$, then the operation would look quite random.

You can realize any group whose cardinality is the continuum this way. Which of them would you consider addition-like or multiplication-like?

Comment: It would help to stress in your second paragraph that transporting the group structure from some *other* group to the set $\mathbb R$ does not "involve" the addition of $\mathbb R$ but, rather, the group operation of the other group. The example in your first paragraph may mislead readers to think otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Please link to [the other question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60759/groups-of-real-numbers)  What was wrong with the idea to take your favorite group and name each element in the operation table with a real number?  For example, the Klein group:
$$\begin {array} {cccc}  0&\sqrt{2}&5.3&\pi \\\sqrt{2}&0&\pi&5.3\\5.3&\pi&0&\sqrt{2}\\ \pi&5.3&\sqrt{2}&0 \end{array}$$
No addition or multiplication in sight.  Silly, perhaps, but I don't understand what you are looking for, so maybe this will help define the question.

Comment: What is the binary operation in this Klein group?

Comment: @Ross: This would be a good answer, but Primeczar wants a group operating on R, not a subset of R.

Comment: I saw "composed of real numbers" as "some real numbers", but I can see he said after I posted that he wants "all real numbers".

Comment: @Primeczar:  The table gives the operation.  For a finite table you don't need a rule, you can just give the result.  I named the elements with various real numbers. You can see it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group

Comment: I think, on reflection, that this deserves a +1 despite not meeting the comment-requirement to use all of R.

Comment: @Primeczar As Ross basically indicates, in some sense, the table and the binary operation, which I'll denote "G", don't differ at all.  You might say the binary operation *is* the table even.  You *can* also view it as a rule if you wish, which I outline as follows: {If x=0, and y=0, then (xGy)=0.  If x=0, and y=5.3, then (xGy)=5.3...}  In other words, as a rule, you can interpret the binary operation as a rule which consists of a collection of "If x=a, and y=b, then (xGy)=z" rules.

Answer (score 1):

How about identify the reals in $(0,1)$ with the canonical set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$?  Of course you need to deal with the ambiguity of trailing 0 versions and trailing 1 versions of the terminating ones-a bijection will solve that.  Then use symmetric set difference operation as your operation.  Biject $(0,1)$ with $\mathbb{R}$ in your favorite way-mine is arctangents.