# Teaching Abstract Algebra for High School Teachers

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, education

I am teaching a class in the Spring for abstract algebra for high school teachers. The goals of this class is to give future high school teachers a deeper understanding of many of the patterns and concepts in geometry, introductory algebra, and trigonometry. What concepts would you consider necessary for students to learn? Also, what topics in high school/middle school math could be explained using abstract algebra? I have a general course outline in place listed below.

First couple of weeks- Review sets, functions, relations, binary operations, and common proof techniques

Next 6-8 weeks - Focus on groups. We will talk about the definition of groups, subgroups, cyclic groups, Cayley diagrams, multiplication tables, Direct Products, quotient groups, LaGrange's Theorem, cosets isomorphisms, homohorphisms, and plenty of examples of groups in geometry, trig, and algebra (such as rotations of a circle, plane isometries, symmetries of regular polygons, symmetry groups of the conics, modular arithmetic, even and odd functions, ect.) These concepts are not listed in the order they will be presented.

The last 4-6 weeks - Rings and fields. We will talk about the definitions of rings, fields, subrings, modules, ideals, Fermat's little theorem, and focus a fair bit on rings of polynomials. We will also talk about the differences between various number systems and compare them to less common number systems (naturals, integers, rationals, reals, complex, dual, and split numbers, and Gaussian integers). If we have time, we will wrap up with splitting fields and field extensions.

Are there any important concepts that are missing?

Comment: $\text{GL}_n$ and $\text{SL}_n$

Comment: FYI, I believe questions like yours are likely to be better suited for the [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this site. Thank you!

Comment: I recommend that you avoid simply trying to give a "watered down" version of the same material and approach used for pure math majors (unless you have little control over what to cover), and instead include applications and topics that are more relevant for high school math teachers. For example, you'll want to look though books such as [**A Concrete Approach to Abstract Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/AConcreteApproachToAbstractAlgebra-W.W.Sawyer) by Sawyer, [**Fascination of Groups**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521080169) by Budden, **(continued)**

Comment: [**Abstract Algebra and Solution by Radicals**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486477231) by Maxfield/Maxfield, [**Famous Problems of Geometry and How to Solve Them**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486242978) by Bold, [**Abstract Algebra and Famous Impossibilities**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387976612) by Jones/Morris/Pearson, [**Matters Mathematical**](https://www.amazon.com//dp/0828403007) by Herstein/Kaplansky. And you'll want to look though old issues of journals such as *Mathematics Teacher* (1950s through 1970s is best), *Mathematical Gazette*, MAA journals, etc. for papers **(continued)**

Comment: such as [*Illustrations of simple group theory*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3614308) by Holland, [*On functions which form a group*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3613150) by Budden, [*A group whose elements are functions*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27962578) by Lichtenberg, [*Group theory for school mathematics*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27956536) by Dean. For student exercises when just beginning the study of groups, some of those I list in my answer to [Groups of real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60770/13130) might be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will check them out this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curriculum looks really good. In Romania we study abstract algebra in our senior year in high school and this is more or less  what is covered here, so I believe that your outline is pretty solid.

However, I think that since you will be talking about groups you should also consider covering group actions. I suggest that you do this because Burnside's Lemma from group theory has several applications in counting problems and these certainly do pop up a lot in high school/middle school maths. You can find plenty of examples of such problems online and you may also consider looking at [this](https://math.mit.edu/%7Eapost/courses/18.204_2018/Jenny_Jin_paper.pdf) paper which briefly discusses the Polya Enumeration Theorem (a generalisation of Burnside's Lemma) and presents applications of this result in chemistry and music theory (which is something pretty cool and useful for a high school maths teacher to know if you ask me).